# Xamarin forms : resources not found exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop

AQ recent update from Xamarin shared project broke my app...

its referencing resource :#0x7f030046 (deciman : 2130903110)

but that ID doesnt exist...(below is the exception in full)

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030046
  at android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030046
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:4360)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2372)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
  at at md500be48de6cc96aeacd65a54dddadb5f5.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at md500be48de6cc96aeacd65a54dddadb5f5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

i've done a clean -rebuild, ive removed the debug & obj folders..
Thoughts?

cheers

Buzz

Comment: Did you remove the app entirely from the device? I’ve had issues where Xamarin doesn’t replace all things and this is the result of it.

Comment: this was the solution

Comment: i also had to do this:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64109/failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v7-appcompat-r-styleable-code-works-for-others-not-my-mac